# Change value of position in a vector + automatically create that position & increase vector-range if needed

Tags: c++, visual-studio, vector

The basic question is above, just an quick example to illustrate:
Let’s say I wanna roll a 6-sided dice until I get a 4 and then play this “game” 10 times.
Now I want to get a very basic probability distribution of how many throws are needed to get a 4. So e.g. in 2 games I needed only 1 throw, in 4 games  three throws, in 3 games 4 throws, and in 1 game 78 throws. So before playing I never actually know how many throws are needed, the game could go on endlessly.
To simplify record-keeping I want to use a vector, where the position/index of the vector indicates the number of throws needed to get a 4 and the value of the position says how often this many throws were needed. So such a vector for earlier example would look sth. like this: {0, 2, 0, 4, 3, 0, [another 72 zeros), 1}.
How would I code this in C++?

(I’m pretty sure that something similar must have been asked before, but couldn’t find a matching question. Also I’m just beginning to learn C++, so please don’t invoke very technical concepts if they aren’t needed to understand the solution.)

```
C++-Code/Pseudocode
vector<int> recordvec = {0};
for (1 to 10){
    game();
    recordvec[game.throwsneededtowin()]=recordvec[game.throwsneededtowin()] +1 
    //How to make sure that I don't get an out-of-range error here if game.throwsneededtowin() is e.g. 1464?
}
print recordvec
```

Comment: You can use `vector::push_back` to increase position and `vector[i] = something` to change value

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but how can I use push_back to increase the vector size to a certain position (instead of just one more)? So in my example if game.throwsneededtowin() is =23 after the first game, how do I change the vector range so that index 23 is included? And is there any way to assign value and increase vector range at once, so e.g. if I write sth. like recordvec[23]++ and position 23 doesn't exist yet for recordvec it is automatically added, set to 0 and then is incremented by 1?

Comment: Yes use `vector.push_back("value");`

Comment: I might misunderstand sth. here, but when using recordvec.push_back(5) do I not just add one element to the vector "recordvec" and then assign this new position the value 5? But what if I want to assign a value at index 78 but the current size of "recordvec" is only 5? Then i would need to add 74 elements all in all and then assign the 79th (with the index 78) the value 5? Can this also be done "vector.push_back("value")" and i'm misunderstanding or is another command needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing to `std::vector`as OP requested

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime> 

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> stats;
    std::srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(std::time(0)));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        int is4;
        size_t throws = 0;
        do 
        {
            is4 = int(std::rand() % 6 + 1 == 4); 
            if (throws < stats.size())
                stats[throws] += is4;
            else
                stats.push_back(is4); 
            ++throws;
        } 
        while (!is4);
    }

    for (auto const &stat : stats)
        std::cout << stat << " ";

    std::cout << std::endl;


    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to do sth. similiar to the question for an school-exercise, where i'm supposed to use vectors, so I can't utilize that solution-way in this case.

Comment: @someonesomewhere I have adapted the code to use `std::vector`

Comment: Works. Thanks a lot.